# Database: Storing Taxes Rates & Information

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let's imagine:
there's a website, a kind of job board. Products are virtual there. There are extra options and fees for posting an entry.

Now, in our country, there's VAT, really complicated rules. Business is located in PL:
- users from PL - VAT rate is 23%
- individual users from EU - VAT rate is 23%
- companies from EU - NP (not apply)
- companies/individual users outside EU - NP (not apply).

Now I'm wondering about the best approach with database design. We have following tables:

```
countries
code VARCHAR(3) PK AI
NAME VARCHAR(200) NN

users
country VARCHAR(3) FK_countries_code
account_type TINYINT //0 - individual, 1 - company
```

When applying tax rules few things apply:
- user location
- user account type.

Do you have any suggestions for database design? I was thinking about altering countries table and applying some denormalization here - creating few columns: `vat_rate_eu_personal`, etc. but this is terrible idea. I was also hinking about implementing new tables: `tax_rates` and `tax_rates_rules` when the information will be stored. However have no idea about structure of the second table.

**Edit**
To make it clear: there's no 0% rule for me, it's called NP (not apply). However, the tax rules have one major requirement: company from EU need to provide valid VAT ID. That's why we created two account types: for company accounts and individual users.

Comment: "there's no 0% rule for me, it's called NP (not apply)". What you *call* the rule doesn't really matter. A rule that doesn't apply is effectively 0% for calculating VAT.  You can't store numeric percentages and strings ('NP') in the same column; they're different data types with different constraints.

Comment: Do you determine whether a user is inside or outside the EU by looking at the user's billing address, shipping address, or something else?

Comment: @Catcall - user country based on the provided address details - that's why we used separate table for countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two broad ways to approach this.

1. Store every possibility.
2. Store only the possibilities that have a VAT rate > 0.

I'd probably store only the possibilities that have a VAT rate > 0.

But your rules look really simple to me, having only two possibilities.

1. Individual users from the EU: 23%. (Poland is still in the EU,
   right?)
2. Every other individual and company in the world: 0%

You can easily determine a users country and whether that user is an individual or a company. The only thing you're missing is the members of the EU.

```
create table EU (
  country_code varchar(3) primary key references countries (code)
);

insert into EU values ('PL'); -- or whatever code you use.
...
```

and so on.  Then you can create a view for looking up the tax rates.

```
create view VAT_rates as
select 0 account_type, country_code, .23 VAT_rate
from eu;
```

Comment: I edited my question. Yes, you're right. We have two tax rates in this case, however I'm thinking about storing specific rules in database, that's the key :)